# How to design PDF with creating dynamic HTML using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to generate a PDF with creating a dynamic HTML table and data using js. I am trying to use jsPDF but not applying CSS (inline or internal both are not working) pdf dynamic created table. I want the same layout as it is. would it be possible using any js (client-side)? do I need to create HTML or need to generate dynamically? I will show multiple records with the header column.

Thanks in advance!

function print() 
{

```
   var table = $('<table class="mystyles"><thead><tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead></table>');
    var name = "Test";
    var email = "TestEmail";
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" +
        name +
        "</td><td>" +
        email +
        "</td></tr>";

    table.append(markup);

    $('#contentId').append(table);

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    doc.fromHTML($('#contentId').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    headerFooterFormatting(doc, 2);


    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
};
```

Comment: Are you creating the project in node environment ?

Comment: You can try Phantom JS

Comment: I am using a simple  Devextreame js dxDatagrid and I want to generate a PDF  report of grid data on a button click. the design layout would own as we want in PDF. (i will create a dynamic HTML table using js function to show grid data in PDF with header and column ).